# segmentation fault when read file in c

Tags: c

I try to write function that get char array, insert line from file is gotten from redirection, and return the length of file.

I tried:

```
#define LINE 256
int getline1(char s[]){
    char ch;
    int length = 0;
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    while(ch != '\n' && ch != EOF){
        s[length++] = ch;
        scanf("%c", &ch);
    }
    s[length] = '\0';
    return length;
}

int main(){
    char line[LINE];
    while(getline1(line) != 0){
        printf("%s\n", line);
        char line[LINE];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but I get segmentation fault and I don't understand why?

input ./main < find_input.txt

find_input.txt:

a

b

**Edited:**

I added `while(ch != '\n' && ch != EOF && length < LINE)` to while but now I get a garbage in line. For some reason I do not exit from while at the end of the file.

Comment: You declare `char line[LINE];` twice. Once outside and once inside the `while` block. The one inside the block is not initialized and may cause a very long `%s` to be printed, with lots of garbage. Remove the definition in the block

Comment: @PaulOgilvie You are correct, but the one inside the block is never used

Comment: @Ctx, not sure...it overrides the definition from outside the block.

Comment: you have to check the length of the array inside getline1 too; What if the line is >= 256?

Comment: what does `line` buffer holds here `char line[LINE];` ? Nothing, its uninitialized char buffer. Please put something into it. Firstly initialize it  `char line[LINE] = {};` & then put something(read from file) into the buffer and pass it to `getline1()`.

Comment: Gal Leshem, do NOT edit out errors of your code for which you seek support.

Comment: ... instead create an answer which demonstrates how you used the comments input to solve your problem. Do not forget to explain.

Comment: Gal Leshem, when I say "Remove the definition in the block" I mean to remove it from your code, try it and report back if it solved the problem. I did not mean to remove it from the code you posted.

Comment: I removed the definition in the block, and get the same error.

Comment: I added  `while(ch != '\n' && ch != EOF && length < LINE)` to while but now I get a garbage in line. For some reason I do not exit from while at the end of the file.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie But it gets effective only in the part after the declaration inside the block, which is (was) empty

Comment: How did you start it and what did you input when you observed the segmentation fault?

Comment: scanf() returns the number of characters read, or EOF... EOF is NOT placed into the variable "ch".  You should be checking its return code (which is an INT) in your while().  In other words "int rc;  rc = scanf("%c", &ch); while(rc == 1 && ch != '\n' && length < LINE) .... "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program fails due to not checking return value of *scanf* function. Also, the expression (ch != EOF) makes no sense in your *while* loop as a part of the controlling expression. You are checking a *char* variable (ch) against EOF. This is nearly always indication of an error in the code. EOF is not a character: It is an integer constant expression with type *int* (and a negative value), that is returned by several standard library functions to indicate *end-of-file* (or an input error sometimes). For instance, the *scanf* function returns EOF if an input failure occurs before any conversion. Otherwise, it returns the number of input items assigned, which can be zero. So the function you aim to implement could be written as:

```
int getline1(char s[])
{
    char ch;
    int length = 0;
    /* The scanf call below will return 1 if it reads a character from stream */
    while (scanf("%c", &ch) == 1 && ch != '\n')
            s[length++] = ch;

    s[length] = '\0';
    return length;
}
```

But the function above has a fatal flaw: it does not know the length of the array in the calling function. The parameter *s* is just a pointer from the function's point of view and it is impossible to determine that information from the pointer alone. It will not stop writing at the end of the array if the number of characters read from the stream is greater than the size of the array. Instead, it continues writing past the end and into memory it doesn't own. **This function cannot be used safely**. For that reason, the array size must be passed as an argument for these kind of functions. So a safer implementation could be:

```
int getline1(char s[], int size)
{
    char ch;
    int length = 0;

    if (size < 1)
            return 0;

    while (length < size - 1 && scanf("%c", &ch) == 1 && ch != '\n')
            s[length++] = ch;

    s[length] = '\0';
    return length;
}
```

This function should be called like

```
getline1(line, sizeof line)
```

provided the original definition of character array *line* is visible.

Note: C Programmers usually prefer using *getchar* function to read one character from *stdin*. Using *scanf* (with %c) for this purpose is not an error per se, but may be inefficient.

Comment: Very Nice Answer!